# Iterating through a Tree and getting certain children in C#

Tags: c#, recursion, observablecollection

I'm currently working with a tree structure defined like this

```
public class TreeNode
{
   private ObservableCollection<TreeItem> nodeItems;
   private ObservableCollection<TreeNode> nodeChildren;
   //public "NodeItems" and "NodeChildren" getters and setters
}

public class TreeItem
{
   private bool isSelected;
   private string Name;
   //public "IsSelected" and "Name" getters and setters
}

public class Tree
{
   private TreeNode rootNode;
   //public getters and setters properties
}
```

and I'm trying to write a function or a `public` property that recursively gets all the `nodeItems` in the `Tree` that have `isSelected == true` and make it a flat collection.

So I wrote this function in the `TreeNode` class, that recursively navigates through the children:

```
public ObservableCollection<TreeItem> SelectedItems()
    {
        ObservableCollection<TreeItem> tempCollection = new ObservableCollection<TreeItem>();
        if (nodeItems != null)
        {
            foreach (TreeItem item in nodeItems)
            {
                if (item.IsSelected == true)
                {
                    tempCollection.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
        if (nodeChildren != null)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode node in nodeChildren)
            {
                tempCollection.Concat(node.SelectedItem()); 
            }
        }
        return tempCollection;
    }
```

but it **always returns an empty collection at the end**.

How can I correct it, and maybe improve it (by using a *Lambda* expression or a *property*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Concat` function on the `ObservableCollection` does not modify any of the arguments. You have to assign the resulting object to your `tempCollection`.

```
    if (nodeChildren != null)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in nodeChildren)
        {
            tempCollection = new ObservableCollection<TreeNode>(tempCollection.Concat(node.SelectedItem())); 
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:** Alternatively, you can use an overloaded private method to not use so many temporary collections:

```
public ObservableCollection<TreeItem> SelectedItems()
{
    ObservableCollection<TreeItem> toReturn = new ObservableCollection<TreeItem>();
    SelectedItems(toReturn);
    return toReturn;
}

private void SelectedItems(ObservableCollection<TreeItem> tempCollection)
{
    if (nodeItems != null)
    {
        foreach (TreeItem item in nodeItems)
        {
            if (item.IsSelected == true)
            {
                tempCollection.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
    if (nodeChildren != null)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in nodeChildren)
        {
            node.SelectedItems(tempCollection);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's just it? Man, I feel so dumb...how can I convert the `IEnumberable` that `Concat` returns, to an `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: AFAIK you have to either to `new ObservableCollection<T>(list1.Concat(list2));` (edited the answer for this) or iterate over the returned object, from `SelectedItems` and add them in turn to the `tempCollection`

Comment: @RiccardoLomazzi added an alternative solution to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your definition of a tree down to this:

```
public class Tree : ObservableCollection<Tree>
{
    public ObservableCollection<TreeItem> nodeItems;
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
public IEnumerable<TreeItem> FlattenIsSelected(Tree tree)
{
    return tree.nodeItems.Where(x => x.isSelected)
        .Concat(tree.SelectMany(t => FlattenIsSelected(t)));
}
```

It's not much more difficult if you keep your current definitions.